# I don't have anyone I report to - should I raise this?

Tags: management

I am a mid level IT contractor and I currently have no one to formally report to in my organization.

Normally this is pretty sweet because there is no one to contradict me when it comes doing what I think is best for the team and project. This is not good because I'm sure I don't always know what's right, and I do not have an appropriate means of seeking advice on what to do in certain situations. 
Should I mingle in the organization to put someone above me?

Comment: Is there someone that "informally" tells you what to do? Or are you just part of a team and doing whatever seems to need doing?

Comment: Hey kiwimatt, and welcome to [workplace.se]. The best answers come to questions that focus on a practical problem you're facing. Right now I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve. If you aren't getting in any trouble, then why do you need someone above you? If you are having a problem due to lack of direction, what is that problem? Those are questions we can help you answer, but as-is it's a little unclear. If you could make an [edit] to your question, it may get you much better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jmac I think there's a very specific practical problem here: "I do not have an appropriate means of seeking advice on what to do in certain situations".

Comment: @Yannis, I fail to see the connection between, *"Sometimes I need to ask about some stuff"* and *"Do I need to find myself a full-time boss?"* -- I think the question would get much better answers and be a better resource if it explained when guidance was needed, and asked how to go about getting guidance (one option being finding someone to play manager).

Comment: There have to be people who are above you.. I am not sure I believe the Q

Comment: You mean that your workload is essentially dealing with support requests from people who clearly aren't your manager? Obvious question, but it doesn't say somewhere in the contract?

Answer (score 10):

Do you have someone in the organization that approves your time sheets? That would be my suggestion for someone that is approving your work for the organization as otherwise you may have the issue of who is making sure your company is getting paid properly.

Answer (score 10):

You should definitely do something. The reason is that you always have a direct superior, but in large and somewhat disorganized organizations neither you nor the superior may now about this connection. Eventually though, things catch up, and this person might realize that you are on their budget, and they will start asking reasonable questions like "What is the value added for me?", and "What have you been doing for the last 6 months, given that I didn't know you exist?".

Typically this happens in a situation where your pay is budgeted by person A, while you are doing work for person B, directly reporting to person C, and there is some communication breakdown between all of these parties.

My advice would be to figure out:

1. Whose budget pays for you. This person is the real boss, because ultimately they are the ones with the decision making power to either keep paying for you or to let you go.
2. Who is the real beneficiary of your work. These people can influence the person in (1) and provide feedback on you.
3. Figure out the relationship between the people in (1) and (2). They might be on the same lateral level, for example the director of an IT department, and a director of finance (whereby the IT director pays for you, but doesn't know anything about your work because you spend your days in finance), or one might report to the other (a director of IT pays for you, but knows nothing about your work because you're supposed to be reporting to one of the mid-level managers). Alternatively, it might turn out that these parties are unrelated and the current reporting structure you fall into is completely broken - if this is the case you should either work to get transferred somewhere more appropriate or work something different.
4. Having established all of the people, and their relationships, you need to make sure that everyone is on-board with what you are doing on a daily basis.

Inaction on your part can put your job in danger, because you never want to have the person paying your salary to question your usefulness. Unless everyone who makes decisions with regards to your employment sees business value in what you're doing, you will be first in queue to be let go.

Comment: Of course, action on their part could also put their job in danger. If the position is not really needed then it could expedite the process of questioning their usefulness. If they are flying under the radar then who knows how long the contract could be milked;)

Comment: Bosses also control pay raises and awards and project assignments. Not working for anyone is the kiss of death organizationally.

Answer (score 1):

I remember being in this situation when the three levels of management above me all resigned in a matter of weeks.  That, however, took care of itself soon enough.

Someone, somewhere, is a 'consumer' of your services. They may be administrative assistants or clerks or people that work in accounting, but they are, ultimately, the ones that use your work.  However, these people aren't your boss.

Their supervisor is responsible for their support.  Therefore, this is someone you need to know, even if they aren't your 'boss'.  At the very least, they will make sure you don't get conflicting requests from anyone else.

In the situations I was in where the organization chart was vague there was generally an 'operations manager' somewhere that oversaw all the people in 'production roles', whatever that means.  Hints as to who does this are: they have a private office, they arbitrate conflicts among the rank and file staff, and they tend to set the agenda of meetings.  The more obvious ones terrorize the staff, but sometimes 'assertive' isn't necessarily 'frightening'.

If you can't find such a person you may discover your area is experiencing a 'power vacuum'. This might be because the organization can't find anyone to run it, it might also mean it's redundant and due to be shut down.